# How to reset global window properties from react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have an app written in react (bootstrapped with cra) and I set a global window property (as an object) when a component is initially rendered inside a useEffect hook and it gets set fine. If I inspect the value of `window.myConfig` with dev tools in the browser, I see the object has the correct properties. When a user selects an option from a dropdown menu I need to reset the object, but the problem is that the `window.myConfig` object (the global property on the window) does not get the new value, it keeps the old value. Is there a special way to do this using react? Here is a code example:

---EDIT---

I tried to add some more information about what I am trying to achieve. I cannot use context or redux. The reason I am using a global variable is because it is used by a third party javascript widget and I am changing to widget configuration when I user selects an option from a dropdown. I hope this is more clear.

```js
const config1 = {
  name: 'name1',
};

const config2 = {
  name: 'name2',
};


const App = () => {

  

  const [config, setConfig] = useState(config1);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.myConfig = config;

    return () => {};
  }, [config]);

  const onDropdownSelect = (option) => {
    if (option === '1') setConfig(config1);
    else if (option === '2') setConfig(config2);
  };

  // ...
};
```

Comment: how do you update the config through setConfig?

if config is an object, the hook will respond to a change in object reference, and not a change in its properties.

Comment: I have added more information now but I see that the hook is not running. I think you are onto something here

Comment: I think you were right; it seems that the useEffect hook was not firing possibly due to the fact that it was an object being set. I think I fixed this issue by being more specific in my deps array.

Comment: yeah, Keep in mind that if reference types are used in hooks dep (arrays, objects, etc) it looks for a change in reference, and not properties. Remember to create new objects, arrays when updating reference state values in react. This goes for the render cycle too.

Answer (score 0):

use Context Provide for solve problem not as window config https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-context-and-usecontext/

Comment: Thanks but it needs to be a global property because it is for a widget

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).